# Ion deep zoom with bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-ion

I've tried to download a bitmap using Ion. However, zooming the image a lot I see that the quality is lower than expected. How can I download it without any quality loss using Ion? I've tried deep zoom and it works if I put the image directly with Ion in the ImageView, but I need the bitmap for some operations. Any idea?

This is the code (giving me the low quality issue):

```
Ion.with(getActivity()).load(url).withBitmap().deepZoom().asBitmap()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, Bitmap result) {
            ...doing stuff....
                });
```

Comment: Please look at the deep zoom sample for the proper way to use deep zoom. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIMltNEAKZY

Comment: @koush if you use bitmaps is a way to prevent to use a downscaled version of the image? I've used deepzoom successfully but it wants the imageview and I don't always has it.